# def model_func(t, a, b, c):

Tags: python, function, equation-solving

I am fitting a function to a power law by using

```
def model_func(t, a, b, c):                                                         
    return a * np.exp(-b * t) + c  

opt_parms, parm_cov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(model_func, x1, y1, maxfev=1000)          
a,b,c = opt_parms
```

The fitted curve looks perfect, but how can I get the exact function printed (like `y=a*b^x`)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: umm `print "Y={0}*{1}^x+{2}".format(a,b,c)` ?

Comment: Thanks that worked, but it is not
 
`Y={0}*{1}^x+{2}".format(a,b,c)` 

but

`Y={0}*{1}^(x/10)+{2}".format(a,b,c)`


how does that come??

Answer (score 1):

If you have your fit variables in `a`, `b`, and `c`, you can just print them…

```
print('y = {} * -{} t + {}'.format(a, b, c))
```